# Will declare a global varible when doing recursion memory efficient and faster?

Tags: c++, recursion

Consider the following code:

```
int main()  {
  int ar[100]={0};
  int n = 100;
  recurFun(ar, n);
  return 0;
}

void recurFun(const int ar[], int n)  {
  if(some condition)  {
    //some code here to manipulate ar[]...
    return ;
  }
  int i;
  //some code to manipulate i
  recurFun(ar, i)
}
```

I heard that the recursion function will make its own variables every time it call itself, **therefore I would expect `ar` is created many times and may cost a lot of memory usage, right?**

What if I declare `ar` as a global array, like below:

```
int ar[100]={0};

int main()  {
  int n = 100;
  recurFun(n);
  return 0;
}

void recurFun(int n)  {
  if(some condition)  {
    //some code here to manipulate ar[]...
    return ;
  }
  int i;
  //some code to manipulate i
  recurFun(i)
}
```

**Will this be more memory efficient?** Since I think there is no reason for the recursion function to duplicate the global variables. However, **will this be slower since many recursion function is visiting a same array**, therefore will cause some overhead.

Comment: A raw array cannot be passed by value. The formal argument declaration `const int ar[]` is equivalent to writing `int const* ar`: only a pointer is passed.

Comment: Slightly OT: As is it, your function is [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), so there with good compiler optimization, there will be no real recursion happening, and thus no copy (even of a pointer or i).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const int ar[]` does not copy the array, it decays the array to a pointer to the first element.

Your global array solution is ever so slightly more memory efficient because it does not pass this pointer around in stack variables, but that doesn't matter. Stack space is free until you overflow it, and whether you use one extra pointer per call should not be the difference between overflowing the stack or not.

Comment: Did you measure the efficiency of the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that the recursion function will make its own variables every time it call itself, therefore I would expect ar is created many times and may cost a lot of memory usage, right?

This is incorrect. Each invocation of recursive function uses a new set of `local` variables of that function - it has nothing to do with your global data. So `ar` is NOT created every time the recursive function is invoke.

Answer (score 0):

> therefore I would expect ar is created many times and may cost a lot of memory usage, right?

No, that's not true.

When you call `recurFun`, only a pointer to the first element of the array is passed to the function. You should not see any performance differences by passing the array to `recurFun` like you are.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no penalty.

The whole array itself is not copied (pointer), and the stack must be resized anyway because of the other parameter etc.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might add a bit more to this question to explain where and how the memory is allocated.

```
int main()  { int ar[100]={0}; recurFun(ar, 100); }
void recurFun(const int ar[], int n)
```

This will stack allocate your array at run-time, and for every recursive call to `recurFun` it will stack-allocate a pointer and an int (in the worst case! Common case probably that tail-recursion is possible and it can reuse the stack).

```
int ar[100]={0};
int main()  { recurFun(ar, 100); }
void recurFun(int n)
```

This will allocate your array at start-up-time in the data segment, and for every recursive call to `recurFun` it will stack-allocate an int (in the worst case! Same as above). Depending on your linker settings, access to this goes through an indirection table, and thus requires 2 pointer access for every usage.

```
int main()  { int ar[100]= new int[100]; recurFun(ar, 100); }
void recurFun(const int ar[], int n)
```

This will dynamically allocate your array at run-time in a dynamically allocated memory segment, and for every recursive call to `recurFun` it will stack-allocate a pointer and an int (in the worst case! Same as above).

Unless the array is very large (>100kb), the first method is preferred.